# GItlab pipeline problem to connect private nexus repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, docker-registry, nexus3

This is my pipeline

```
stages:
  - build

.tags:
  tags:
    - test-integration
    
image: docker:20.10.16

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

  NEXUS_URL: test.registry.test.local
  NEXUS_USER: admin
  NEXUS_PASSWORD: test!test

services:
  - docker:20.10.16-dind


build_image:
  extends:
    - .tags
  stage: build


  script:
  # Add the Nexus registry certificate to sss trusted CA certificates
    - mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL
    - cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL/
    - cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/intermediate.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL/
    - cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cert.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL/
    - docker login -u $NEXUS_USER -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD $NEXUS_URL
    - docker images
```

but i have problem

```
$ docker login -u $NEXUS_USER -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD $NEXUS_URL
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "test.registry.test.local/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

also i try this pipeline

```
stages:
  - build

.tags:
  tags:
    - test-integration
    
image: docker:20-dind
services:
  - name: docker:20-dind
    command: ["--tls=false"]


variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  NEXUS_URL: test.registry.t.loestcal
  NEXUS_USER: admin
  NEXUS_PASSWORD: test!test



build_image:
  extends:
    - .tags
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:19.03-dind

  script:
  # Add the Nexus registry certificate to sss trusted CA certificates
    - mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL
    - cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL/
    - cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/intermediate.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL/
    - cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cert.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/$NEXUS_URL/
    - docker login -u $NEXUS_USER -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD $NEXUS_URL
    - docker images
```

and i have problem that docker is not running but login in nexus oss

```
$ docker login -u $NEXUS_USER -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD $NEXUS_URL
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/. Is the docker daemon running?
```

is anyone now solution ?

i use gitlab-runner as docker executor

this is `config.toml` of gitlab runner

```
concurrent = 20
check_interval = 20
shutdown_timeout = 20

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = " DeVops Side"
  url = "https://gitlab.test.com/"
  id = 59
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-08-15T17:17:42Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
#    volumes = ["/certs", "/cache"]
    volumes = ["/certs","/cache","/usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates:ro"]
    shm_size = 0
```

I try many configuration but not working , i use runner as a linux ubuntu machine and use as a docker executor not shell .